# Solving $x^2+19=y^5$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, ideals

I was given several exercises and there is a particular one, I am not able to solve.

Let it be given that $Pic(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−19}])$ is a finite group of order $3$. Use this to find all integral solutions of the equation $x^2 + 19 = (x + \sqrt{−19})(x-\sqrt{−19})= y^5$.

I have absolutely no idea what to do. Could anybody help me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is unique pair of solutions: $(\pm 22434, 55)$.

Comment: Are you sure you want $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$? This is not a Dedekind ring, and the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ actually has trivial Picard group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers which satisfy $x^2 + 19 = y^5$. Then $(x + \sqrt{-19})(x - \sqrt{-19}) = (y)^5$.

If you can find that $(x + \sqrt{-19})$ and $(x - \sqrt{-19})$ are coprime ideals, (if $19 \mid x$ would hold, then $19 \mid y$ and $19 = y^5 - x^2$ where the RHS is divisible by $19^2$ - contradiction) then $(x + \sqrt{-19})$ is the fifth power of some ideal $I$; since the class group would have order $3$ (it doesn't), $I$ must be principal, and $x + \sqrt{-19}$ a perfect fifth power.

Equating $x + \sqrt{-19}=(a + \frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}b)^5$ gives you $$x = a^5 +\frac{5}{2}a^4b - 45a^3b^2 - 70a^2b^3 + \frac{155}{2}ab^4 + \frac{101}{2}b^5$$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$5a^4b + 10a^3b -40a^2 b^3 - 45ab^4 + 11b^5 = 2;$$ the lower equation implies that $b = \pm 1$ or $b = \pm 2$. We calculate

if $b=1$, then $5a^4 + 10a^3 - 40a^2 -45a + 9 = 0$ with no integral solutions;

if $b=-1$, then $5a^4 -10a^3 - 40a^2 + 45a + 13 = 0$ with no integral solutions;

$b = 2$ gives solutions $a = 5$ and $a = -7$ and therefore $a+\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}b = \pm 6 + \sqrt{-19}$;

$b = -2$ again gives none.

So you must have $x + \sqrt{-19} = (\pm6 + \sqrt{-19})^5 = \pm 22434 + \sqrt{-19}$;

so $x = \pm 22434$ and $y = (22434^2 + 19)^{(1/5)} = 55$ is the only integral solution.

Comment: I have a doubt: after showing that $I$ is principal, why is $I$ generated by an element of the form $a+b\sqrt {19}$? Is it not true that we shall first determine the ring of integers of the algebraic number field in question? Also, I think that $a$ and $b$ might be half-integers. Then your next implication that $b=\pm 1$ cannot hold. Of course this problem could be tackled by some more analysis of the equations, so do you mind to modify it? Thanks.

Comment: @awllower You're right, I was confused by OP's use of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$. I edited the question. Result shouldn't change.

Comment: @Mathoman Thank you; I'm still somewhat confused about whether it really answers your question - see my comment on your answer..

Comment: Yes, the statement of the exercise is also very confusing to me, but it clearly says that I should use that $Pic(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−19}])$ is a finite group of order $3$ in order to find all integral solutions. If one day I will get a correction of it in class, I will let you know what we wrote!

Comment: I'm not sure the proof is quite right, since when you show that the ideals of any solution pair would be coprime, you don't say why an ideal of norm two shouldn't divide both. In fact, I think that the ideals of the solutions you give are not coprime, both being divisible by $p=(2,\sqrt{-19})$. The answer is still valid, because by looking at norms we know that any power of $p$ dividing $(x+\sqrt{-19})$ is a multiple of $5$, but the proof as it stands is wrong. Please someone correct me if I've made a mistake.